# how to fix warnings in shinken

Tags: networking, debian, shinken

I'm on Debian, and I've installed Shinken for monitoring. Shinken is working well, but I have some issues. I've 13 IT PROBLEMS WARNING. How to fix warnings in shinken?

```
WARNING for localhost/CPU Stats
WARNING for localhost/Disks
WARNING for localhost/Disks Stats
WARNING for localhost/Kernel Stats
WARNING for localhost/Load Average
WARNING for localhost/Memory
WARNING for localhost/NET Stats
WARNING for localhost/NFS Stats
WARNING for localhost/NtpSync
WARNING for localhost/Read-only Filesystems
```

Comment: Please format your question so that it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine the reason for the warning and then take appropriate action.  If for example you have constantly high cpu load or disk activity you need to free up resources on your server.

Shinken has configuration parameters that allow you to override the default values that triggers warnings and disable them if thats what you require.